# how bitcoin core generate addresses?

Tags: bitcoin-core, address-generation

how does bitcoin core generate addresses and where can they be found in the data directory?

Comment: To generate addresses or to save the ones generated? Maybe you are talking about the wallet file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin addresses can be created anywhere with any programming language.
they're just like the result of 1 + 1 = 2.

if you are looking for the function they're using for getting a new address here you go:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/4ad3b3c72c73d61e0a0cab541dca20acf651320d/src/wallet/rpcwallet.cpp#L135

When you make RPC call 'getnewaddress' that function will be called, and addresses keys are already generated (`keypool`) and saved into `wallet.dat` file.